#  die() but only within the <?php ?> tags?

Tags: php

If I have code such as:

```
<html>
...
<?php
....
die();
?>
....
</html>
```

then the entire page execution stops, and the final html does not get shown. is there a way to only leave the php within the enclosing php tags?

Comment: Your HTML views should never `die`.

Comment: Why do you think you need `die()`?

Comment: I'm used to labelled loops/scope in Java :-) I just wanted to know the easiest way to leave the scope without resorting to returning and and setting variables to indicate so to leave nested ifs. However, i've resorted to doing it C-style as suggested.

Comment: or better yet use a template engine or framework, and separate the application/business logic from the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is based on same condition, otherwise it wouldn't make sense.

```
<html>
...
<?php
....
if (! condition) { //skip if not needed
  ...
}
?>
....
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't ever call `die()` inside an HTML script.  If you are calling `die()` as part of `mysql_query()` error checking, for example, you should instead wrap the call in an `if()` statement.  This doesn't only apply to MySQL, of course. You can use this in place of any instance where you would call `die()`.

```
// Instead of this...
$result = mysql_query() or die();

// Do this...
$result = mysql_query(...);
if (!$result) {
  $errorstring = "an error occurred producing your data";
}
```

It is generally considered bad practice to include a lot of application logic within the HTML. Instead do these things at the top of the script and store the output in variables for reuse later.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `die()` and expect execution will continue. That is illogical and impossible

Comment: Is there a way to leave the scope within the tags. perhaps something like goto?

Comment: No. Goto is REALLY discouraged and it's impossible.

Comment: Try using a control structure like [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is have an external php script and iframe it into the page, or use jquery to ajax it in. Then if it dies nothing will be displayed in the iframe, or div (if you use jquery), but you can still die